# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" while executing mongorestore on localhost

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

What I have:

1. Mongodb 3.0.2 running on localhost (Windows 7 Pro)
2. Local .bson file (~60GB)
3. 32 GB RAM

What I do:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongorestore --collection collection_name --db db_name F:\path_to_bson\archive.bson

Result:

1. 100% RAM utilization when 30% is done
2. A lot of errors like this: "error: WSARecv tcp 127.0.0.1:49587: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." appear when ~60% is done
3. Not all documents restored as result.

If I use another archive to restore (which is smaller, ~ 6GB) - it is OK

Question: How to get all documents restored from .bson ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this problem on windows a moment ago (client and server on same machine). Same code works fine on Linux.

I got around the problem by decreasing the number of items inserted / updated per bulk operation.

I'm doing this in an app. I don't see an option in [mongorestore docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) for reducing per bulk operation entry count.